# Camel File component should not rename file when an exception is thrown

Tags: apache-camel

I have camel route configured as below:

```
<route id="text-file-route">
                        <from 
                                uri="file:files/merchant?antInclude={{include-file-type}}&amp;initialDelay=1000&amp;delay=1000&amp;move=${file:name.noext}.processed" />
                        <split streaming="true">
                                <tokenize token="\n" />
                                <process ref="splitBatchAdapterProcessor" />
                                <process ref="merchantStreamProcessor" />
                                <process ref="merchantTableProcessor" />
                                <to uri="mock:dummy" />
                        </split>
                </route>
```

With current configuration the file gets renamed even if an exception is thrown while processing the file. 
What i want is, the file should only be rename if no exception is thrown while the file.

I an using camel 2.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn on shareUnitOfWork so the splitter returns back the exception so the file consumer can rollback. You can read more about this at: http://camel.apache.org/splitter

```
  <split streaming="true" shareUnitOfWork="true">
```